Using a Zalgo text as part of a website hostname?
I know about the weird texts in the well known Regex-HTML answer here on Stackoverflow:
ZA̡͊͠͝LGΌ ISͮ̂҉̯͈͕̹̘̱ TO͇̹̺ͅƝ̴ȳ̳ TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ
After some googling I found this is was done with combining characters in Unicode and this is apparently has the nickname Zalgo Text (which seems to stem from the mentioned answer).
Just for fun I thought about making the url of my homepage contain these extra accents (I have full control over DNS and SSL on that one).
Using https://zalgo.org/ I created N̷̗͑ȋ̷̪ē̷̫l̶̙͝s̵̤̈́   (i.e. Niels in zalgo style).
But when trying to use that as a webpage name https://xn--nls-3qa35jj4bnb5gva5ircn7klicc77buh.basjes.nl/ , my browser (Chrome) immediately converts this into the punycode equivalent https://xn--nls-3qa35jj4bnb5gva5ircn7klicc77buh.basjes.nl/ (which is no fun).
Note that the editor here on Stack Overflow does the reverse! 
You enter the puny code version and it renders the intended Zalgo!


I fully realize that browsers have projection against Homograph attacks (i.e. letters that look the same/similar but are different) but in this case the letters are normal ASCII ... they just have some extra accents (on some of the zalgo websites you can also strip the accents to show this).
So my question is what boundary in Chrome does my experiment violate?
Is it possible (and if it is ...how?) to make my homepage be a Zalgo looking thing?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDN_homograph_attack#Accented_characters

Turns out that Chrome as an extensive checklist that indeed also includes this.
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/main/docs/idn.md#google-chrome_s-idn-policy
Sadly even a pure Emoji does not seem to work and shows the punycode in Chrome. https://xn--1ug66v4685b.basjes.nl/
